# RubyMine-Like Autoformat in Vim

Tags: ruby, vim, rubymine, autoformatting

Is there a way to get RubyMine-like autoformatting in vim?

Example I have this code:

```
def some_method
  hash[:key  ] =  "hello"
end

def some_other_method
  x =  [ "hello",   "world"]
end
```

I want to hit something similar to Cmd+Shift+L (in RubyMine) and have vim output this:

```
def some_method
  hash[:key] = "hello"
end

def some_other_method
  x = ["hello", "world"]
end
```

Comment: I don't think such a thing exists as a plugin and it definetely doesn't as a built-in feature. Did you consider recording a macro and/or creating a custom mapping? Did you actually do some research before asking?

Comment: @romainl I did a bit of research and I came to the conclusion that I'd have to write some custom regular expression substitution to get rid of white space across a file like that. I asked here because I couldn't find anything that made the solution immediately obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nowadays we have a nice tool called [rufo](https://github.com/ruby-formatter/rufo) which will autoformat the code for you. You can run it automatically with tools like [Neoformat](https://github.com/sbdchd/neoformat)